# Generate test and fixtures based on model from cake console

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I already have model file, but that model doesn't have any test or test fixtures currently. Is there a command in cake console, that would generate test and test fixtures based on already created model. I'm using cakePhP 2.9.

Thank you!

Comment: Just check the book for these basics. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html I know reading is not very popular these days but developers should read, especially documentation, it's a crucial part of the profession.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create following files wit following commands.

```
cake bake test model "modelName"

cake bake fixture "modelName"
```